# How to vlookup each comma separated value in one cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, excel-2016, vba

I have worksheet A:

[image: a]

I have another worksheet (WS) B:

[image]

**What I want:**
I wanna use a `Vlookup` formula at cell C3 with the formula like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,b!A2:B3,2,FALSE)
```

**However:**
 I don't know how to make it **look up multiple comma separated values (csv) in one cell** (Note that there are cells that can go up to 10 csv)

Logic wise, cell C3 of WS A should :

- Lookup value B2
- From the table array of WS B
- Looping through cell A2 of WS B, it should check for "1-ABC", "2-ABC", "3-ABC".
- Since it finds a match at "3-ABC" then C3 will return the Unique Acc ID at B2 of WS B
- Then hopefully I can drag down the formula to many many records...

***Can this be done using formula or it better to do it via VBA? If VBA, how can I do this?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the asterisks as wildcard like that

```
=VLOOKUP("*" & B2 & "*",b!A2:B3,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks. The answer is simpler than I thought. But trying to vlookup 1M records and dragging it down for ~30k rows makes it super slow. But yeah I think there isn't any other way for now.